# Call Array into One Line Variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to transpose mysql value (dynamic) to colum name, as an example

```
SELECT kdsatker,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425121 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425121,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425122 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425122,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425129 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425129,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425131 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425131,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425132 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425132,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425134 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425134,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425287 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425287,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425513 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425513,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425514 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425514,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425515 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425515,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425518 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425518,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425519 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425519,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425764 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425764,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425791 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425791,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425792 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425792,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425793 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425793,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425811 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425811,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425911 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425911,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425912 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425912,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425913 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425913,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425915 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425915,
MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=425999 THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M425999
FROM(SELECT kdsatker,kdakun,sum(jumlah) as jumlah FROM tb_simponi GROUP BY kdsatker,kdakun) as newdata GROUP BY kdsatker
```

the MAX CASE loop based on the value data, My last work is create array based on mysq data result

```
$sql=array();
while
($baris=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>
    <?
    $kodemak=$baris['kdakun'];
    $sql[]="MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun=".$kodemak." THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M" .$kodemak;
    ?>

<?}
```

The problem is how to call the $sql variable which is contain all array loop with comma delimited into one $sql variable

```
SELECT kdsatker, $sql FROM(SELECT kdsatker,kdakun,sum(jumlah) as jumlah FROM tb_simponi GROUP BY kdsatker,kdakun) as newdata GROUP BY kdsatker
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions.  Use something current, like `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was not mistaken, you can use implode to glue the array into one serial string.

```
$sql= implode(",", $sql);

SELECT kdsatker, $sql FROM
(SELECT kdsatker,kdakun,sum(jumlah) as jumlah
 FROM tb_simponi GROUP BY kdsatker,kdakun) as newdata GROUP BY kdsatker
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is an solution to make your `SQL Query` Dynamically by your conditions :

```
$sql      = [];
$sql[]    = "SELECT kdsatker";
while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $kodemak = $baris['kdakun'];
    $sql[] = "MAX(CASE WHEN kdakun={$kodemak} THEN jumlah ELSE NULL END) AS M{$kodemak}";
}
$select = " FROM(SELECT kdsatker,kdakun,sum(jumlah) as jumlah FROM tb_simponi GROUP BY kdsatker,kdakun) as newdata GROUP BY kdsatker";
$sql = implode(', ', $sql);
$sql = $sql . $select;

echo $sql;  #Here is your Final Query String
```